# SapUi5 + Phonegap - loading Sap libraries

Tags: javascript, eclipse, visual-studio-2012, cordova, sapui5

I've recently found a javascript framework called SapUI5 and I wanted to use it for a Hybrid cross platform app. I've created a PhoneGap project for WP8 in visual Studio 2012, added SapUI5 libraries and created a basic app with two pages and navigation in one index.html file. And when I deployed it to the windows phone 8 emulator it shows an (unable to get property) exception.
I've also created a PhoneGap project for Android in eclipse to create an Android hybrid app and done the same as in the visual studio project. And when I deployed it to the android emulator, it worked perfectly.
Can some one help me with this issue? Thank you in advance!

Comment: SAPUI5 is optimized for Chrome, Safari and Firefox. It can be that WP8's browser (what ever it is) is not properly supported.

Answer (score 1):

UI5 does not seem to officially support Windows Phone Browsers at all:
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/BrowserSupport.html

Anyways since it is supporting IE9+ it should work on Windows Phone as well. At least starting from IE10 the mobile version shouldn't differ from the desktop version: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Mobile#Version_10